# Clonar Div Al Clickear Y si Ya Esta Clonado Al Clickear De Nuevo Eliminar Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas Colegas, La Verdad, soy Nuevo En Jquery Y Javascript, Les agradecería Me Ayudaran Con Este Problema. Tengo Una serie De Botones, Los Que Deseo Clonar Y Agregar Un Nuevo Div, Vale, Eso Ya Lo Hice, El Problema El Botón Clonado Si Ya Existe. Algo Mejor Explicado, Click, Clonó El Botón Y Lo Agrego A Un Nuevo Div, Y Si Vuelvo A Clickear Sobre El Mismo Botón, Este Clone El Eliminar De El Nuevo Div. Y Así Con Los Demás Botones, Aquí los Dejo Algo de Lo Que Tengo. Gracias A Todos Por La Ayuda.

```js
var ClickButtons =  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.button'));
      
         ClickButtons.forEach(function (element, i){
      element.addEventListener('click', function (e){
       e.preventDefault();
      var Copy = $(element).first().clone().addClass('clone').appendTo(".agg-bet");
       
       
             
        
       });
      
      });
```

```css
.agg-bet{
background-color:#0c3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
                             <td class="mb-option-button">
                             <button type="submit" class="button">         
             <div class="name-team-option">Levante</div>
             <div class="name-value-option">5001.00</div>
        </button>
                             
       </td>
                             <td class="mb-option-button">
        <button type="submit" class="button">         
             <div class="name-team-option">Leganés</div>
             <div class="name-value-option">5001.00</div>
        </button>
       </td>
                     </tr>
                        <tr>
                             <td class="mb-option-button">
        <button type="submit" class="button" >         
             <div class="name-team-option">Girona</div>
             <div class="name-value-option">5001.00</div>
        </button>
       </td>
                             
                     </tr>
                       


</tbody>
</table>

<div class="agg-bet"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué escribes de esa forma? Es muy incómodo de leer

Comment: gracias por la opinión, dejare de hacerlo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar este snippet, lo que hace es crear eventos individuales, dichos eventos guardan un *estado* a partir de él se decide si se debe agregar el elemento ó bien eliminarlo

```js
;(function()
{

function crearEvento(objetivo, destino)
{
  var agregado = false
  var clon = objetivo.cloneNode()
  
  return function(e)
  {
    if (agregado)
      {
        destino.removeChild(clon)
        agregado = false
      }
    else 
      {
        destino.appendChild(clon)
        agregado = true
      } 
  }
}

var botones = document.querySelectorAll('#botones input[type="button"]')
var destino = document.getElementById('resultado')
for(boton of botones)
  {
    boton.addEventListener('click', crearEvento(boton, destino), false)  
  }

}())
```

```css
#resultado 
{
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div id="botones">
<input type="button" value="op1" />
<input type="button" value="op2" />
<input type="button" value="op3" />
<input type="button" value="op4" />
</div>
<div id="resultado">
</div>
```

la parte importante del código es `crearEvento(objetivo, destino)` el cual crea un evento para agregar el elemento *objetivo* a un *destino* especifico.

Comment: Eduen muchisimas gracias, lo pondre en prueba. y gracias enserio. :)

Comment: Eduen, si ud observa mi código, puede observar que dentro del botón ay dos div, esos dos div son los que nescesito que se clonen, y hasta ahora no lo he conseguido, podrías hecharme una mano. Gracias.